# remove a row from data table

Tags: r

I want to exclude the last number in the table so that my data only has the following numbers

```
accuracy <- c(18,25,23,22,20,14,31,20,24,6,24,12,16,24,23,15,14,24,42,19,27,13,23,6,28,30,22,33,12,21,38,16,17,11,29,18,22,21,29,19,17,28,20,35,14,14,35,30,18,37,23,8,19,38,24,28,12,25,12,32,19,20,27,25,24,32,16,16,13,21,30,23,5,18,20,33,18,37,20,11,32,13,30,18,7,27,18,24,26,14,13,21,35,25,18,25,34,34,24,23)
```

[image]

Comment: `data3[ , complete.cases(data3)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding

```
data3=data3[-(101:102),]
```

after creating data3.